# A simple way to calculate the potential electrical output of a magnet.

Tags: electromagnetism

I am a software engineer. This I understand very well. I am attempting to build a prototype with arduino circuits. This I know a little less about. Part of my project requires a electro-magnetic generator. This I know nothing about.

I looked up Gauss's law and embarrassingly the math is a bit above my pay grade. All I want is a simple way to calculate the potential electrical output of a magnet. For example if I use a refrigerator magnet to power my generator its going to do much less then a magnet from a subwolfer. I know that there is also a direct relation to the spacing of the copper wiring that it's passing through but for this example please assume that all other external variables are a constant. How do I determine which magnet would best suit my needs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not actually [Guass' Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_law) (which concerns itself with electric fields) you want, but [Faraday's Law of Induction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday%27s_law_of_induction).

Even then, the *only* way to answer this question is to *measure* the magnetic flux available to you. If you are going to use a permanent magnet, then you need a magnetometer as these things are not labeled for strength (indeed it would be very hard to design a useful unit of the generic strength of a permanent magnet because the field geometry is highly variable from example to example).

Unless you just happen to have access to a quality magnetometer, it is almost certainly easier to simply prototype the device and *measure* the output (which is something you can do with an oscilloscope and a multimeter).

If you do have a magnetometer, you can map the field; guestimate the coils design and relative motion; and estimate the current as a function of time. This doesn't let you off prototyping of course, it just means a good chance of few prototype cycles.

Comment: Gah yeah I figured I could use a multimeter and just test test test. I was hoping there was a less painful way. Such is life. Thanks for the answer.